# applicationDidBecomeActive doesn't appear to work on device - only in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, device

This is the body of `applicationDidBecomeActive` in my app delegate

```
if (myViewController != nil) {
    [myViewController myMethod];
}
```

It seems to fire ok in the simulator, but not on device.  Any clues?

EDIT/Update:  I've tried moving the code to the applicationWillEnterForeground, but either place I put the code it works fine in the simulator AND on device when running w/ a development profile.  When I build for my deployment profile and run it as an ad hoc build on the device is when it conks out.

Comment: What's the device? Older iPhones (e.g. iPhone 3G) and iPod Touches behave differently.

Comment: could applicationDidBeconeActive be called before myViewController is initialised?

Comment: @onnoweb - good call - it seems to be working ok on my 1st gen iPad, but on my iPod touch (running iOS 4.3.2) (not sure how old it is, but it's got retina and camera) is where it doesn't work.  Hrmmm...  If this is the cause, anybody know of a solution?

Comment: @Autopulated - the view controller is initialised and visible before switching to a different app, so yes, it's there for sure.  It's when I switch back and the app re-enters the foreground that I want to fire the event

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider registering your view controller for a NSNotification named `UIApplicationWillEmterForeground` and dealing with it that way, rather than relying on the cenfrwlized app delegate. It will make things easier to manage.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't help.  The fact that it works in the simulator tells me I'm putting the code in the right method - I'm just wondering why it's not working on device.